# How to use angular pipes in window.open with url?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
<div class="member-img" onclick="window.open(childEpisode.File_URL | fullPath)">
</div>
```

the `fullPath` is a pipe that concatenates the domain part to the URL i.e. `file_URL` which is relative.

but it doesn't work and shows nothing.

If I use it with img `enter code here`then it works but i want it the way I have posted above.

working example:

```
 <img [src]="childEpisode.File_URL | fullPath" [alt]="childEpisode.Name_AR" class="member-thumnail img-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement it like this:

```
<div class="member-img" (click)="openMyLink(childEpisode.File_URL | fullPath)">
```

then in `YourComponent.ts` file implement the method like this:

```
openMyLink(link:string){
  window.open(link)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In html template use Angular Event binding:

```html
<div class="member-img" (click)="openURL(childEpisode.File_URL)">...</div>
```

In the Component ts file inject the `FullPathPipe` class and use it's `transform` method:

```ts
constructor(private fullPathPipe: FullPathPipe) {...}

openURL(url: string) {
  const transformedURL = this.fullPathPipe.transform(url);
  window.open(transformedURL);
}
```

**Note:**

- The pipe operator is not allowed within Template statements.
  https://angular.io/guide/template-statements#syntax
- Template statements cannot refer to anything in the global namespace such as `window` or `document`.
  https://angular.io/guide/template-statements#statement-best-practices